# Compile C: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

I'm a totally beginner.

I wanted to compile C by MinGW in Visual Studio Code,
but I got an error code at the terminal in Visual Studio Code.
At first, I created a file just under Windows (C:).

Source code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal

```
PS C:\vscode> gcc hello.c
ingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mn@16'
ingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The contents of your source file could be relevant.  Please present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That is a linker error. Check your build tools. linker is not able to find the symbol WinMain@16

Comment: Need some code to look at...

Comment: Looks like it is trying to compile a gui app instead of a console app. The compiler / linker flags and settings

Answer (score 1):

With no code... my best guess would be you don't have `int main()` at the beginning of your program OR `main()` is named something other than `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried gcc for Windows, but I would compile only with:

```
gcc hello.c
```

or may be with:

```
gcc hello.c -o program.exe
```